# How do you compare RemoteObject(s) during remote debugging?

Tags: remote-debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm referring to [RemoteObjects specified in the Chrome Debugging API 1.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/runtime#type-RemoteObject).

#### Background

I'm trying to associate subsequent call frames to previous call frames.

Let's say:
I set breakpoints on the functions `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`.
I run the following:
`a(b(c(d())));`

The execution pauses, and I receive the `Debugger.paused` notifications for each function and resume each time.
On each `Debugger.paused` notification, I receive an array of `CallFrame`s. However, the `objectId`s in each `CallFrame` object and its properties are all unique. As such, I am unable to compare them by their `id`.

Anyone knows some way to do this?

The `Runtime.callFunctionOn` and `Runtime.evaluate` allow me to execute code on single objects based on their id, however, it doesn't seem to allow me to execute code on *multiple* objects so I can't do something like check `CallFrameA.objectX === CallFrameB.objectY` (for example).

I'm also not sure if retrieving the objects through the API and doing a deep equality check is a good idea. One way would be doing a recursive `Runtime.getProperties` call and checking equality of all the properties except for the unique `objectId`.

Answer (score 1):

1. I suggest you file an issue against the Chromium or WebKit to support unique ids for objects – a thing implemented V8's native debug protocol.
2. Actually you can provide several ids to Runtime.callFunctionOn via its *arguments* parameter.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I can pass multiple arguments in the `Runtime.callFunctionOn` method. I missed that, somehow. I'm trying that out now and will see how far I go with that.